# png image is not displaying after "reDraw"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using custom png images for items of .tabBarItem of my UITabBarController.
But my png images are too big (64x64), so I use the method below to redraw the image in a smaller rect (for example, make the size parameter (25,25) ).

```
-(UIImage*) getSmallImage:(UIImage*)image inSize: (CGSize)size
{
    CGSize originalImageSize = image.size;

    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    float ratio = MAX(newRect.size.width/originalImageSize.width,
                      newRect.size.height/originalImageSize.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newRect.size, NO, 0.0);

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:newRect cornerRadius:5.0];

    [path addClip];

    CGRect projectRect;
    projectRect.size.width = ratio * originalImageSize.width;
    projectRect.size.height = ratio * originalImageSize.height;

    //projectRect.origin.x = (newRect.size.width - projectRect.size.width) / 2.0;
    //projectRect.origin.y = (newRect.size.height - projectRect.size.height) / 2.0;
    // Draw the image on it
    [image drawInRect:projectRect];
    // Get the image from the image context
    UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // Cleanup image context resources
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return smallImage;
}
```

Every image I use was returned by this method. Everything was fine on simulators, but those images were not displaying when I test them on my iphone.
But if I abandon the method above and import the image directly like this: `self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Input"];` Then the images were correctly shown on my phone, but only too big.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this question by myself.
After hours of debugging, here is the problem:
in the method given above, `origin`property of `CGRect projectRect`was not set.
After I set both origin.x & origin.y to 0, everything worked out.

Tip: every time you meet a WTF problem, be patient and try to test your code in different ways. 'Cause in 99.9% of this kind of cases, there is something wrong with your code in stead of a bug of Xcode.

Though I still don't know why the code in my question works well in simulators, I'll let it go because I guess someday when I become an expert, this kind of question would be easy as well as silly.